# C++ subscription operator overload

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, subscription

I'm working on brushing up on my C++ during some project downtime and have created a a Linked List project to do so.  In this project I would like to return the current value at a set index.  I've already got a method to do this, but want to work it out with an operator overload.

To that end I did the necessary research to brush up and have created the following code (I won't subject everyone to my code and will only paste the pertinent sections):

```
T& operator[](const int index);

template<class T>
T& LinkedList<T>::operator[](const int index)
{
  try
  {
    if(!isIndexValid(index)) throw ior;

    Node<T> *temp = _head;
    for(int i=1; i<=index; i++)
    {
      temp = temp->Next;
    }

    return temp->Value;
  }
  catch(exception& e)
  {
    cout << e.what() << endl;
  }
}
```

In my main function I have the following line:

```
int foo = list[5];
```

Everything looks good to me, but when I compile I get the following error:

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'LinkedList<T>' to 'int'
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

Thank you!

For those that have asked, here is how the Node class is defined:

```
template<class T>
class Node
{
  public:
    Node();
    Node(const T value);

    T Value;
    Node<T> *Prev;
    Node<T> *Next;
};
```

And here is the declaration for my list variable:

```
LinkedList<int> *list = new LinkedList<int>();
```

Comment: Which line does the error refer to? Also, how is `list` declared?

Comment: I would much prefer that the parameter to `operator[]` is of type `size_t`, rather than `int`.

Comment: What is the definition of `list` variable? Where do you call the line `int foo = list[5];`? And why your function returns nothing if the exception was caught? Also, is `count` your alias for `cout`? :)

Comment: podkova - I have added the declaration for list above.  Also, you are right, I had a typo and that should have been cout, not count.

Answer (score 0):

You don't call your operator, since it expect `LinkedList<int>` but you provide `LinkedList<int>*`.
You could dereference:

```
 T foo = (*list)[5];
```

Or, you define your operator to be appliable to the pointer type.

Answer (score -1):

How is your node class defined? You return temp->Value;
But your function signature is saying you will return a reference to your class (T&). If node.Value
is an int, that could be your problem.

Comment: -1 Questions asking for clarification should be posted as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to post as a comment. The solution would work if my suspicion is correct.

Comment: I realize that you don't have enough rep to comment yet, but the fix for that is to increase your rep by asking good question and giving good answers -- not by skirting around the rep limit by posting a comment as an answer.  It might seem like a pain, but 50 rep is easy to come by.

Comment: Silkut - I have added the definition for the Node class above.

Answer (score -2):

> In my main function I have the following line:
>
> int foo = list[5];
>
> Everything looks good to me, but when I compile I get the following error:
>
> error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'LinkedList' to 'int'
>
> Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

Compiler error message says it all. You are use `LinkedList<T>` which is a generic type and the type is represented by `T`. So you cannot assign an element of type `T` to an `int` at compile time. Since compiler will only know what type of `LinkedList` at run-time, you can only assign it to an object of type `T`

How to fix it: replace the line  `int foo = list[5];` by following line.

`T foo = list[5];`

Comment: Please, do a favor for the world and buy a good C++ book. Your answer means that you don't understand anything about C++ templates. **EDIT:** I have not readed your last line, I only focused my comment to *"... compiler only knows what type of linked list at runtime"*. But your last line is... I haven't got enough words...

Comment: What I really don't understand is why other stupid answers in other threads I have readed in SO got a lot of downvotes, and this not have 100k downvotes.